# Iterate through NSDictionary and save it into an array of object type

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, nsdictionary

As the title states, I would like to iterate through a NSDictionary and save the single entries into an array of object type.
I am currently struggling to read out the single entries of the NSDictionary, as I cannot simply call them with entry[index] and count upwards.

I've got a local JSON file named "Clients", which I get into swift. The file looks like this:

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "id": 3895,
            "phone": 0787623,
            "age" : 23,
            "customerSince" : 2008
        },
        {
             "id": 9843,
            "phone": 7263549,
            "age" : 39,
            "customerSince" : 2000
        },
         {
             "id": 0994,
            "phone": 1093609,
            "age" : 42,
            "customerSince" : 1997
        }
    ]
}
```

What did I do?
I created a class ClientObjects, which looks like this:

```
import Foundation

class ClientObjects{

    var id : Int = 0;
    var phone : Int = 0;
    var age : Int = 0;
    var customerSince : Int = 0;      
}
```

Next I realized the JSON import into Swift, which works properly.
When I debug the session, the `jsonResult` variable contains the data of the JSON. But somehow I couldn't manage to process the data into the array of the object type *ClientObjects*.

```
   // instantiate the ClientObjects as an Array
        var clientsArray = [ClientObjects]();

        func getData() {

            if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Clients", ofType: "json")
            {
                if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)
                {   
                   do {
                        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            //print(jsonResult["clients"]);
                            // this print call returns the whole content of the JSON array

                           if let clients = jsonResult["clients"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                                for client in clients {

                                   clientsArray.append(client);

                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                            print("API error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                    }
                    }
                }

            }
}
```

The goal is, that I can print out single attributes of clients, like:

```
clientsArray[0].id;
```

Can somebody please give me some advice on my issue?

Answer (score 1):

### First of all let's take a look at ClientObject.

1. It should be a `struct`
2. It should be simply named `Client`
3. The properties should be constants without a default value
4. It should have a failable initializer
5. The `phone` should be a `String` (please change your JSON accordingly)

Like this

```
struct Client {
    let id: Int
    let phone: String
    let age: Int
    let customerSince: Int

    init?(json:[String:Any]) {
        guard let
            id = json["id"] as? Int,
            phone = json["phone"] as? String,
            age = json["age"] as? Int,
            customerSince = json["customerSince"] as? Int else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age
        self.customerSince = customerSince
    }
}
```

### Now let's read the JSON

```
func getData() {
    do {
        guard let
            path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Clients", ofType: "json"),
            jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path),
            jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary,
            jsonClients = jsonResult["clients"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

        let clients = jsonClients.flatMap(Client.init) // <- now you have your array of Client

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("API error: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why that `guard` stuff in `ClientObject`? The JSON is doubtless complete non-optional. There are so many examples where the JSON is received from SQL databases which send reliably **all** fields with **all** non-optional values otherwise the entire data package is `nil`.

Comment: @vadian: because I don't want the app to crash if for some reason the JSON does not contain all the required fields. It's a golden rule for robust code. However the OP is free to ignore that part but it's how I would do it.

Comment: But you can also guard the code to death and this JSON contains all keys/values. Once again, most of the SQL databases send all or nothing.

Comment: @vadian: I see your point but I can't know who generated this JSON and under which constraints. All I know is that I don't want to use the `!` because it has the power to crash the entire app.

Comment: A **local JSON file** might be safe enough ;-)

Comment: @vadian: well... I agree on this :D I think having both our answers in this thread is a good thing. The OP and future readers will be able to choose the best approach based on their scenario.

Comment: Joking aside I see so much "overguarding" examples and a grave of meaningless exclamation and question marks. I apologize for being nitpicking.

Comment: @vadian: I appreciate any criticism, especially if it comes from the user in the first position of the monthly chart for the `Swift` tag ;) I totally see your point. I am just used to be paranoid about JSON data. I am sure these comments we added here can only make more valuable this thread.

Comment: @appzYourLife I'm with you here.  Much of the philosophy of swift is to prevent the hidden errors that occur with Objective-C and it's absurdly broad usage of nil and complete lack of error checking and handling.  Much better to be explicit about what your assumptions are, and `guard` is how you do that.  ! is the most over and misused operator in swift.

Comment: Hey everybody. Thank you for answering so quickly! I asked the question before I went to bed yesterday and didn't expect to get feedback by today!
I'll have a look at your code after I come home from work :)

Comment: I just tried to implement your code. But when I debug it, it always jumps into the "else {return}" statement.
The warning next to it is, that "a cast from NSDictionary to unrelated type [[String:Any]] always fails". Do you have any idea, how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Does no one of you two has a clue? I'm still stuck on this :/

Comment: @Manuel: so the problem seems to be that `jsonResult["clients"]` is a `NSDictionary` and not a  `[[String:Any]]`. Are you sure the file you put into your question is the same you are using now? Because looking at your question `clients` does contain an `Array`.

Comment: @appzYourLife: it seems that the app executes the 
`jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary`
but then ignores the `jsonClients = jsonResult["clients"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
let clients = jsonClients.flatMap(Client.init)`
(I tried to print the `jsonClients` right before the else statement and it simply ignored it)

Comment: @Manuel: why don't you try [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/)? It makes JSON management way easier.

Comment: @appzYourLife: Thanks, I guess this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `ClientObjects` objects and assign the values to the appropriate properties.

```
...
let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
if let clients = jsonResult["clients"] as? [[String: Int]] {
  for client in clients {
    let newClient = ClientObjects()
    newClient.id = client["id"]!
    newClient.phone = client["phone"]!
    newClient.age = client["age"]!
    newClient.customerSince = client["customerSince"]!
    clientsArray.append(newClient);
  }
}
...
```

It's recommended to name classes with singular forms in this case `ClientObject`

And no `if - let` nor Foundation types like `NSDictionary` nor `MutableLeaves` options in the `NSJSONSerialization` line.

Comment: Hey vadian, thank you too for your help! I'll have a closer look at your solution after I returned from work today :)